# EXPSS: Is there a way to add value labels for multiple columns without having to list each of them?

Tags: r, expss

Want to add the same value labels to multiple columns using expss but there is too many to list.

Am looking for something like this but for a range of variables instead (e.g., for q1-q30)

```
val_lab(df[c("q1", "q2", "q6","q30")]) <- c("Awful"=1, "Bad"=2, "Ok"=3, "Good"=4, "Great"=5)
```

Some codes I tried but did not work

```
val_lab(df[c("q1" %to% "q30")]) <- c("Awful"=1, "Bad"=2, "Ok"=3, "Good"=4, "Great"=5) 
val_lab(df[c('q1' %to% 'q30')]) <- c("Awful"=1, "Bad"=2, "Ok"=3, "Good"=4, "Great"=5) 
val_lab(df$q1 %to% df$q30) <- c("Awful"=1, "Bad"=2, "Ok"=3, "Good"=4, "Great"=5)
```

Is there anyway around this? Thanks!

Comment: `val_lab(df[paste0("q", 1:30)]) <- ...`

Comment: Thank you so much, that works great! Do you happen to know how to add labels if let's say the column names are different ("apple", "pear" .., "orange") but are next to each other and use the same labels?   <- c ("Love It"=1, "Neutral"=2, "Meh"=3, "Hate It"=4)

Comment: `df[4:6]` refers to the 4th through 6th column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below set value label for range of variables.

```
mtcars = mtcars %>% 
    let(
        (vs %to% carb) := set_val_lab(vs %to% carb, 
                                      c("one" = 1)
                                      )
        )
```